# Ksoap2 ClassCastException

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

Hi I am trying to build an app where data are retrieved from a webs service.  I am using KSOAP2 to get the data from the web service..
the data is getting passed in arraylist from the web service.. I need to save the data received in a new arraylist but I am getting ClassCastException when I try to save the object into array list..

below is the code

```
class NetworkConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ViewSchedule> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected ViewSchedule doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("username",username);
            request.addProperty("startdate",currentDateString);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();

            ArrayList<String> recivedlistItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            recivedlistItems=(ArrayList<String>) result; // exception caught here


            if(!recivedlistItems.isEmpty())
            {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        addItems("some crap");

                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        addItems("No bookings");

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(LoginScreen feed) {



    }
```

Here is code of my wsdl (web-service)

```
public synchronized ArrayList<String> View(String username, String startdate ) {

    System.out.println("\n entered the method");

    try {
        /* Create object of the Connect class */

        Connect connect = new Connect();
        /*
         * calling the Connection method of Connect class to establish a
         * database connection
         */
        Connection conn = connect.Connection();

        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        /* Creating a query to be executed with prepared statement */
        String query = "select title,startdate,enddate from bookinginformation where username=? and startdate=?";

        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, startdate);
        // stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        boolean empty = true;
        while (rs.next()) {
            empty = false;
            String title =rs.getString(1);
            String S_date=rs.getString(2);
            String e_date=rs.getString(2);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String temp="";
            temp = sb.append(title).append("-").append(S_date).append("-")
                    .append(e_date).toString();
            listItems.add(temp);
            System.err.println("\n added  \n");
        }

        if (empty) {
            System.out.println("\n no data");
            //return "false";
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return listItems;


}
```

Below is the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive
at com.example.androidfrontend.ViewSchedule$NetworkConnectTask.doInBackground(ViewSchedule.java:162)
at com.example.androidfrontend.ViewSchedule$NetworkConnectTask.doInBackground(ViewSchedule.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight change to Swayam's code worked for me..

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            int childCount = result.getPropertyCount();

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                String temp= result.getProperty(i).toString();
                recivedlistItems.add(temp);
            }
```

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! And so foolish on my part that I missed something so obvious; trying to typecast instead of calling toString() was indeed embarrassing.

Comment: `SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();` Even this worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
recivedlistItems=(ArrayList<String>) result; // wrong code
```

`result` is an `Object` and you are trying to cast into a `String`. And hence the exception.

Try this code.

```
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); 
            int childCount = result.getPropertyCount();

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                recivedlistItems.add(result.getProperty(i).toString()); //**edited** after Srikanth pointed it out
            }
```

Comment: what's the best way to do it ?

Comment: What is returned by the Web-service ? It is an Object or a String ?

Comment: it is an arraylist which s returned from the web-service.. I need to save the data into a new arraylist

Comment: I could be more accurate if you gave me the WSDL of your web-service but I guess the best thing you can do is take the response in a SoapObject and then use getProperty(index) to retrieve each of the items in the ArrayList and add them to the new ArrayList.

Comment: What is the URL of your web-service ? Is it on a local machine or can I see the SOAP definition via the URL ?

Comment: Yes it's on the local machine...
`private String METHOD_NAME = "schedule"; // our webservice method name
private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculate.backend.web.org";
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; // NAMESPACE + method name
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.4:8080/AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl";
`

Comment: Actually you included the java code in the question. That is not what I was looking for. I wanted the definition in SOAP, which can be seen by clicking the name of your web-service. Anyway, did you try using the SoapObject method that I told you ?

Comment: I would be glad if my code helps you out. And please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if you find it of any use. :)

Comment: `String[] stringList = new String[childCount];` this should have been like this if I am  not wrong?

Comment: Ignore the stringList. The updated answer directly adds them to the ArrayList instead of the String Array.

Comment: And yes, you are correct though. I assumed that you would initialize it. :)

Comment: Still the same exception swayam when i use this `SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); ` instead of `Object result = envelope.getResponse();`

Comment: Previously you were getting the exception on this line recivedlistItems=(ArrayList<String>) result. Where is the exception coming now ?

Comment: Now it's for `SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();`

Comment: Is it again the ClassCastException ?

Comment: This is an example of a web-service SOAP definition : http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit . Can you please give me the SOAP definition of your web-service ? That would help me understand the exact response format of the service.

Comment: I am not using separate SOAP definition as such.. I am connecting it from my android client by defining it the beginning `private String METHOD_NAME = "schedule"; // our webservice method name private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculate.backend.web.org"; private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; // NAMESPACE + method name private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.4:8080/AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl"; `

Comment: I understand what you are doing. Go to "http://192.168.0.4:8080/AndroidBackEnd/services/Calculate?wsdl" on your local system. Click on the "schedule" method and you will get the SOAP definition automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15619/discussion-between-srikanth-and-swayam)

Comment: `SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    int childCount = result.getPropertyCount();

             int i;
             for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
              String temp= result.getProperty(i).toString();
                 recivedlistItems.add(temp);
             }`  This code snippet worked.. @swayam Thanks for the help

Comment: OH!!!! How foolish on my part!!! I was typecasting it to String instead of calling toString()! Embarrassingly silly mistake of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what returns `envelope.getResponse();`, but I see you store it in an `Object`.

Then you are trying to cast it to an `ArrayList<String>`. That won't work, an Object is not an ArrayList.

Comment: So How can I get data into the arraylist?

Comment: Use add() method: `recivedlistItems.add(my_object);`

Comment: main objective is to store the value obtained from webservice in to a arraylist.. the object has the values obtained.. is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: @Andy.. I didn't really get what you meant by using `recivedlistItems.add(my_object);`

Comment: If I understood correctly, you asked how to store data into the `ArrayList` (first comment above). And then I said that an array list object has the `add()` method which takes as an argument an object that can be added to the list. And then I showed a concrete example with your `recivedlistItems` object.

Comment: I wanted the result in the SOAP object to be populated in the arraylist.. I got that sorted.. Thanks For the help Andy :)